# Saving strings as binary to save memory

Tags: kdb

I have a large string column that takes up a lot of space. If I save it in the table as a  binary instead of a string will that save space?

I saved a list of strings to disk, and a list of equivalent binaries through:
`{-8!x} each strList`

On disk files are saved in binary anyways, but it seems the binary file is larger than the string list.

Also the binary list is larger than the string list if I run -22! on it. I know -22! Is uncompressed size, so is there anyway to measure the actual size?

Comment: Actual size on disk depends on the encoding of the string and its content. Generally speaking, UTF8 tends to be the most compact for many uses.

Comment: `-22!` is a short cut for `count -8!`. The binary representation is being compounded:
`-8!"abc"0x01000000110000000a0003000000616263`
`-8!-8!"abc"
0x010000001f00000004001100000001000000110000000a0003000000616263`

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem here. Somehow compressing the strings is just a remedy. Why is the entire column loaded into memory? Can you not splay to disk and only read in what you need? Is kdb the right database for very large text data?

Comment: For example when logging raw queries. They are stored as strings and can get very long when these queries have table arguments with many rows. Cutoffs are set after a certain length, but the smaller the size means we can store longer queries.

Comment: Ok but the point remains that this logging doesn't need to be retained in memory. It can be written to disk as strings, using the out-of-the-box compression if necessary. I still think you're over-engineering the solution if you're trying to covert to binary in-memory

Answer (score 1):

Running `-8!` is giving you the IPC format. It will take up more space.

You should look in to compression to save space:

- https://code.kx.com/q/kb/file-compression/
- https://code.kx.com/q/wp/compress/

For short strings some options are available to encode:

- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#j10-encode-binhex

If the strings are large you could look in to compressing them individually:

- `-18!` https://code.kx.com/q/basics/internal/#-18x-compress-byte
- `.Q.gz` https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#gz-gzip

Comment: So there is no way to compress strings in-memory?

Comment: Answer edited to include `-18!` and `.Q.gz`.